# Clip raster with postgis outputting result in clipping geometry extent

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster, c

I want postgis `st_clip` to output clipped result in extent of initial clipping geometry.
Currently, it's `crop` option can be set to output either in initial raster extent or in extent of intersection between initial raster and clipping geometry.

Here is a test case:

```sql
WITH blade AS (
  SELECT
    st_tileenvelope(11,1238, 638) geom
),

butter AS (
SELECT
  st_addband(
  st_makeemptyraster(
    256,
    256,
    st_xmin(t),
    st_ymax(t),
    (st_xmax(t) - st_xmin(t)) / 256,
    - (st_ymax(t) - st_ymin(t)) / 256,
    0,
    0,
    3857),
    '8BUI'::text,
    1) AS rast
FROM
  blade,
  st_translate(geom, 1000, 1000) t
)

SELECT
  st_width(clip),
  st_height(clip),
  st_envelope(butter.rast) AS raster_envelope,
  blade.geom AS blade,
  st_envelope(clip) AS clipped
FROM
  butter,
  blade,
  st_clip(butter.rast, blade.geom, TRUE) clip;
```

I'm using a random tile as a clipping geometry, then making a test raster by just shifting it by 1000 meters north and east, then clipping it.
Resulting raster size is 243 x 243 and is an intersection between clipping geometry and initial raster.

Image below shows the operation:
Red square is a clipping geometry, green square is initial raster extent, and hashed area is clipping result extent.

[image: clip result]

I'd like a result to be 256 x 256 pixels and it's extent to look like this:
[image: wanted clip result]

I've tried to recompile postgis after changing [this code](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/raster/rt_pg/rtpg_mapalgebra.c#L3148) in `rtpg_mapalgebra.c` file a bit, but with no luck yet.

Comment: Which value do you want the geom area not intersecting with the raster be filled with?

Comment: Any value that NODATA is set to.

Comment: @nextstopsun Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH blade AS (
  SELECT ST_MakeEnvelope(0, 0, 4, 4) geom
), butter AS (
  SELECT ST_AddBand(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(4, 4, 1, 5, 1), '8BUI'::text, 4) rast
), blade_as_raster AS (
  SELECT ST_AsRaster(geom, 4, 4, '8BUI'::text, 2) rast
  FROM blade
)
SELECT ST_MapAlgebra(a.rast, b.rast, '[rast2]', '8BUI'::text, 'FIRST', NULL::text, '[rast1]') rast
FROM blade_as_raster a, butter b;
```

Comment: Does this work for multichannel rasters?

Comment: ST_MapAlgebra() works band per band...

Comment: So you really need to call ST_MapAlgebra times number of bands and then union results to a multiband raster. That's quite inefficient.

Another issue is that you get pixel alignment error if you call ST_AsRaster on arbitrary geometry (e.g. tile boundaries).

Comment: You can control the alignment with some variants of ST_AsRaster().